# Background worker continuously running issue c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

I have created a c# project using background worker. It contain a "Start" button for starting background worker. This is my code.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace Test
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        int status = 0;

        private void btnstart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Background worker started successfully");
            btnsave.IsEnabled = false;
        }

        private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {

                if (worker.CancellationPending)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    return;
                }
               Console.WriteLine("Status : " + status);
                if (status == 0)
                {
                    status = 1;
                }
        }

        private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("worker completed");
          btnsave.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

But every time, i have click on start button, i got output like this

```
attempt 1.

Status : 0
The thread 0x23dc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Status : 1


attempt 2.

Status : 0
The thread 0x148 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Status : 1
Status : 1

attempt 3.

Status : 0
The thread 0x128 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Status : 1
Status : 1
Status : 1
```

I am starting the background worker only after the existing worker is completed. Then why is the "status" log is getting printed like this.

Comment: you are registering the event handler multiple times, without _unregistering_. so the do work event handler is called multiple times.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem results from the event handler assignment:

```
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
```

This is done every time you click the button. Since its a += you assign it multiple times.

Just add the event handler in the window initialization:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace Test
{

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        int status = 0;

        // should be called when the window is loaded
        private void ApplicationStart()
        {
            worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
            worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        }

        private void btnstart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {            
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("Background worker started successfully");
            btnsave.IsEnabled = false;
        }

        private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {

                if (worker.CancellationPending)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    return;
                }
               Console.WriteLine("Status : " + status);
                if (status == 0)
                {
                    status = 1;
                }
        }

        private void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("worker completed");
          btnsave.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Romano Zumbe, it is working fine